# Can I make my do while loop create a new random number every time it loops?

Tags: c++, random, do-while

Can I make my do while loop create a new number from my pseudo random number every time the loop comes around again?  If so, how?'

EDIT: Sorry, it's in C++

EDIT2: I just want a new number between 0 and 3 (0,1,2,3) every time the do...while loop goes around for an integer

Comment: You haven't told us what language you are attempting this in.

Comment: a little more detail please.  Do you want to generate a new random number based on a previously generated random number or do you want to generate numbers using some standard random number generator

Comment: What does your code look like currently? Is there a problem with just "putting the function call inside the loop"?

Comment: I already have the random pseudo integer in the do...while loop, but it just keeps selecting the same number over and over again.

Comment: Bob, why don't you show us the code? Try to use rand()%4 and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

While you might like the following example:

```
do
{
  new_number = out_of(my_pseudo_random_number);
}
while(true);
```

You may find it more useful:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));   // Initialize once at program startup.

    do
    {
         int number = rand();  // generate new random number,
    }
    while(true);
}
```

(But I'm absolutely not sure what your're asking for)

Answer (score 5):

This will specifically make random numbers from 0 t0 3.
You don't necessarily need the iostream/cout statements except for the output I do.

rand() % 4; creates a random number from 0 to (not including) 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;

    //initialize random seed
  srand(time(NULL));

    //make some numbers
  do{
        num = rand() % 4;
        cout << num;
  } while(true);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use rand(), and especially never, ever use rand() % N. The result will be about as random as http://xkcd.com/221/ .

Comment: @David what other solution do u poropose

Comment: Just to name two, Boost and the GNU scientific library have excellent random number generators, extremely good for all but cryptographic purposes. There are plenty of others out there. In comparison, rand() ranges from extremely poor to just so-so.

Comment: @David While I would normally agree with you, I doubt that a more robust random number generator is really necessary in this case...